# How can I remove my library from Maven JCenter?

Tags: android, repository, bintray, jcenter

I have uploaded my android library on https://bintray.com and linked it with Jcenter repository http://jcenter.bintray.com/. 
Now I want to remove this library from JCenter repository. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

**Unlink a package from JCenter is available only for paying customers, OSS users can't unlink a package from JCenter.**

In case you want to remove your package from Jcenter you only need to unlink your package.
Enter your package, click on "Un-Link" button and then choose Jcenter.

However, important information you need to know about deleting content (taken from Bintray [User Manual](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_managinguploadedcontent.html#_deleting_content))

> **An important note about deleting any material:**:
>   Any package, version or file you have published, may now be an integral part of someone else’s project and deleting them may damage their work (deleting unpublished files is not a problem since they are not visible to anyone else)
>
> Note: if your package has been linked to someone else’s repository and then you delete the package, Bintray will automatically create a copy of this package. This means that even though the data was deleted, the **data still exists in another version somewhere**.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>

[image]

Comment: What if I've deleted the package before un-linking it with JCenter?

Comment: If you delete the package from JCenter, Bintray will automatically create a copy of this package in JCenter.

Comment: @Royg Is it possible to un-link from jcenter after deleting the package?

Comment: @DineshKumar not that I know of... This is that you won't break other users build.

Comment: @DineshKumar, you can always publish a new version, more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389987/3719024