# JFrog Bintray:delete package and relink to JCenter

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

I am newbie to publishing library to Jcenter.
I had uploaded my Android gradle plugin library to JFrog artifactory.The library is

https://bintray.com/mmrx/pngquantGradlePlugin/pngcompress

And then,I clicked the button 'link to jcenter'and it linked to jcenter successful.

compile 'com.mmrx.pngcompress:pngcompress:1.0.0'  was worked in my Android project.

after a while,i found some bugs in the plugin library,and deleted the version 1.0.0 which had lined to the jcenter before.And uploaded the new library to the jforg artifactory with the version code 1.0.0.

below the "Linked to" label,the JCenter icon still there.

Then i found the "compile 'com.mmrx.pngcompress:pngcompress:1.0.0'" was not working.the error message is

`Error:Could not find com.mmrx.pngcompress:pngcompress:1.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/AndroidStudio3/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/mmrx/pngcompress/pngcompress/1.0.0/pngcompress-1.0.0.pom
    file:/D:/AndroidStudio3/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/mmrx/pngcompress/pngcompress/1.0.0/pngcompress-1.0.0.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mmrx/pngcompress/pngcompress/1.0.0/pngcompress-1.0.0.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mmrx/pngcompress/pngcompress/1.0.0/pngcompress-1.0.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mmrx/pngcompress/pngcompress/1.0.0/pngcompress-1.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mmrx/pngcompress/pngcompress/1.0.0/pngcompress-1.0.0.jar
Required by:
    project :`

I want to update the library in JCenter.Any suggestions?

Recreate a new repository and upload my library and link to JCenter again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to recreate another one. To update a library on JCenter you need to update your library **version name** and **version code**, and then rebuild and upload into Bintray again, after upload success then you click on **Publish** new version.

=> Then your library will available in JCenter.

If the old version already on jCenter so whenever you update version of the library you no need to "Add to jCenter" again, it will automatically do that you only need to increase your library version and upload to Bintray is enough

Comment: The link between jfrog and jcenter was missed because i deleted the all the version in jfrog.I had ask JFrog Support for help and they helped me relink jfrog to jcenter.